# Mapping dict values based on keys in a list comprehension

Tags: python

Lets say I have a dictionary where the keys are substring I want to use for a str search. I want to see if the keys exist in the elements of a list, and if they do, I'd like to set them equal to the value of that key and if there is no str match, set it equal to 'no match'.

```
d = {'jun':'Junior', 'jr':'Junior', 'sr':'Senior', 'sen':'Senior'}
phrases = ['the Jr. title', 'sr jumped across the bridge', 'the man on the moon']
```

This is what I've tried, however I just can't seem to fit in the 'no match' statement in the list comprehension. Help appreciated. PS. would like to stick with a dict/list comprehension method for my specific use case

```
# Tried
[[v for k,v in d.items() if k in str(y).lower()] for y in phrases]

# Output
[['Junior'],['Senior'],[]]

# Desired Output
[['Junior'],['Senior'],['no match']]
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected output, please? The description is helpful but somewhat confusing.

Comment: Please see last line under '# Desired Output'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add an `or ['no match']` to replace the empty list (which is falsey) with your `['no match']` placeholder in the outer list comprehension.

```
>>> d = {'jun':'Junior', 'jr':'Junior', 'sr':'Senior', 'sen':'Senior'}
>>> phrases = ['the Jr. title', 'sr jumped across the bridge', 'the man on the moon']
>>> [[v for k,v in d.items() if k in str(y).lower()] or ['no match'] for y in phrases]
[['Junior'], ['Senior'], ['no match']]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have now is pretty close to what you're looking for. All your missing is the no-match condition. However, and my guess is that you tried this, you cannot put an else condition in a list comprehension that way. Fortunately, if you use generators, you can go over the list comprehension again to add in the else-condition as a separate if-condition:

```
[x if len(x) > 0 else ["no match"] for x in 
    map(lambda y: [v for k, v in d.items() if k in str(y).lower()], phrases)]
```

Everything inside the `map` does the exact same thing as what you have already; the map simply transforms this to a generator that can be iterated over. I then perform the other condition on the intermediate result. This code will produce the following output:

```
[['Junior'], ['Senior'], ['no match']]
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you only need to check if list is empty and append 'no match'. For that check @Samwise's answer which is very simple and does the job. But if you need to check for complex conditions, then that would not work.

For that, you can iterate the resulting list again and do whatever operation on it you want like this:

```py
# if item will return false if item is empty like you have []
[item if item else 'no match' for item in [[v for k, v in d.items() if k in str(y).lower()] for y in phrases]]

# For any other complex conditions, modify if condition (for example maybe you want to append 'no match' if length of item is less than or equals to 3.
[item if item and len(item) <= 3 else 'no match' for item in [[v for k, v in d.items() if k in str(y).lower()] for y in phrases]]
```